# Docker Mysql: What causes SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection timed out?

Tags: mysql, laravel, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

When running queries in my Docker I get this error, for example

```
php artisan clear-compiled
In Connection.php line 664:

  SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection timed out (SQL: select `id`, `name` from
   `users` where `profile_is_public` = 1 and `status` = 1 order by `created_at
 ` desc limit 6)
```

What are common cases for the connection timed out error? What could be wrong with my config? Maybe it could be something with mysql socket? How to find out?

I think I entered correct user and password.

`docker-compose.yml`

```
version: '3'

services:
  web:
    build: ./webserver
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
    volumes:

      - //docker/dockertest/webserver/app:/var/www/vhosts/app
    links:
      - db:db

    command:
       - /usr/local/bin/apache2_install_composer_dependencies.sh

  db:
    image: mysql:8.0
    container_name: db
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    command: --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
    environment:

      MYSQL_DATABASE: myDb
      MYSQL_USER: test
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: test
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: test
    volumes:
      - //docker/dockertest/install/db_dump:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
      - persistent:/var/lib/mysql
    networks:
      - default

  phpmyadmin:
    image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
    links:
      - db:db
    ports:
      - 8000:80
    environment:
      MYSQL_USER: test
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: test
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: test



volumes:
  persistent:
```

Laravel `.env`

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
#host points to Docker container
DB_HOST=db
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=myDb
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=test
```

**Update**

Simple PHP Script like this works, but Laravel does not (still same error)

```
$servername = "db"; $username = "root"; $password = "test"; $dbname = "myDb";
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

$sql = "SELECT * FROM Person";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "id: " . $row["id"]. " - Name: " . $row["name"]. "<br>";
    }
} 
$conn->close();
```

Comment: what is the point of this volume? `- //docker/dockertest/install/db_dump:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d` if you have large amounts of data in the folder it could be slow performance of the volume

Comment: @MichaelStClair to add a small test db into docker container

Comment: that most likely is your problem, I'm assuming you aren't working on a linux machine. At least on Mac when you mount a directory from the host into the docker container, read/write performance is going to be extremely slow, which is probably leading to your timeout. I would start up the container and then use `docker cp` to get the test db into the container

Comment: If this is the case why can I execute mysql queries in `docker-compose exec web bash` without timeout?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turned out I had wrong env variable name in `config/database.php` for DB_HOST (it was like  `'host'=> env('DB_HOST_1', 'some ip')`)... Did not notice at first. Now it works